# Getting a 'Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.' error despite the extension being loaded

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm getting spammed with `Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.` in my logs, despite having the `redis.so` extension installed on MacOS. I installed the Redis extension by running `pecl install redis`, which succeeds with the following message:

```
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.12/pecl/20180731/redis.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/redis-5.1.1
Extension redis enabled in php.ini
```

By running `phpinfo()` in `tinker`, I can see that my loaded `php.ini` is

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
```

If I open up `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`, `extension="redis.so"` is listed at the top of the file.

What makes this more and more strange is that if I dig deeper into where the original `Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.` error is coming from, it looks to be in `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:76`, which looks like this:

```
throw new LogicException(extension_loaded('redis') ? 'Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension.'  : 'Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.');
```

So according to this, the extension **isn't** loaded. But if I load up `tinker` again and run `extension_loaded('redis')` then I get a `true` result.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on here. Why does `PhpRedisConnector` not see that the extension is loaded?

For completeness, I've also removed the `Redis` alias from my `app.php` file as instructed to by the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who installed Redis with `composer require predis/predis`, as described in the Laravel official documentation.

In `config/database.php`, change:

```
'redis' => [

    //'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
```

Comment: Notes: 
1) PhpRedis is a PHP extension (written in C) and require additional C extensions. 

2) Predis is a PHP package written in PHP.

3) Predis it's a little slower than PHP Redis (but I never had performance issues with it in production). =]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is just a workaround to use predis instead of PHPRedis. If you still want to use PHPRedis and still facing the same issue as the main question then maybe you are running into the same issue as me. In my case the `Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled` error only throw out if running the Job by crontab. Turn out that somehow the version of PHP which using in the crontab is not the same as the PHP version that I installed the PHP Redis to. So here is what I did:

- Find out where is the current PHP path:

```
    MacBook-Pro:hpt hantran$ which php
    /usr/local/bin/php
```

- Change the crontab from

```
* * * * * cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hpt  && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

- To:

```
* * * * * cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hpt  && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The original answer can be found here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/please-make-sure-the-php-redis-extension-is-installed-and-enabled?page=1#reply=659249

Comment: I do agree with you. I had the similar problem.

Run: `php -m | grep redis`

If you do not get redis listed, that means the terminal emulator / cli you are using, it's aliased php binary do not have the extension enabled.

In that case try finding the original binary that you've enabled the redis.so extension.

Run `whereis php` this command, it'll show the current php binary path. 

You can even try running `cd /usr/bin && ls | grep php`

to see if there's more php binary available. In my case I had installed the extension for php-fpm profile.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your env file

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis     <---Add this line-->
```